# Simulate a custom Event using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

```
class AgGridWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AgGridReact onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.this(bind)}
  }
  onCellClicked= (event) = > {
    event.setDataValue(newValue);
  }
}
```

I have a wrapper component **AgGridWrapper** around **AgGridReact** (AgGridReact is a node module which helps to create HTML Grids). In this example when i click on any cell on the AgGrid it will change the value of the cell.

I want to test this onCellClicked event. so i did the following.

```
const wrapper= shallow(<AgGridWrapper />);
const agGridReact = wrapper.find(AgGridReact);

const eventObject={};
agGridReact.simulate('cellClicked',eventObect);
```

My intention is to simulate the cellClicked event and check whether the value of the cell got changed or not.
But here i dont have access to the agGridReact's **setDataValue()** method.
so i am not able to mock this **eventObject**.

I got stecked here for a couple of days now. and i am under the impression that its technically not possible to  test this functionality because **setDataValue** is not accessible to us.

Any Suggestions on this??

Answer (score 3):

As `simulate` does nothing different than just call a function that lives under the `on{propName}`. For some reason this only works for the standard events but in the end there is no different than call it by yourself:

```
const eventObject = {setDataValue: jest.fn()}
gGridReact.prop('cellClicked')(eventObect);
expect(eventObject).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: setDataValue method internally does some DOM manipulation and i actually would like to test whether the Manipulation is done properly or not. Do you have any idea how i can do this?

Comment: You can't test this, and also why do you want to test it here. I would assume that the `AgGridReact` component has its own unit tests, so the only thing that you should test here is that the events was added correctly. Everything else should be better tested in and end to end test.

Comment: Make Sense.Thanks for the help.